# SQL Server 2008 R2 Patindex for Restore Job

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to write a script to grab a file name, and grab the database name from the name.

`MSSQLNET_acap_439_FULL_20131117_020001.bak`

This is what it looks like, and I want the `acap_439` part as the database name.

The string is sort of like this, but not exactly what I am looking for. I don't do a lot of SQL work as the network guy, so I am lost.

```
select @dbName = left(@filename,datalength(@filename) - patindex('%_bd_%',reverse(@filename))-3)

select @dbName = left(@filename,datalength(@filename) - patindex('%_LLUF_%',reverse(@filename))-3)
```

Just not sure where to go, and I am sure someone can look at this and say bam, this is what you do.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are the rules? Do you need to just chop offthe rightmost 25 characters and leftmost 9?

I can't remember if it's LENGTH or LEN in SQL Server but does this give you what you want?

```
set @dbname = LEFT(@filename,LEN(@filename) - 25)
set @dbname = RIGHT(@dbname,LEN(@dbname) - 9)
```

(Done in two steps to avoid convoluted nested functions)